# Looking for Regex Pattern

Tags: regex

Currently I got this:

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}$/\.{1}/^[0-9]{1,3}$/\.{1}^[0-9]{1,3}$/
```

It should accept the following:

- 0.0.0
- 00.00.00
- 000.000.000

It should not accept:

- 000.000.0000
- 0000.000.000
- 000.0000.000
- .0.0
- 0..0
- etc.

Comment: Do all of the digits need to be the same, or is it only the *number* of digits that needs to be the same in each group? I.e. `1.1.1` should be OK, but is `1.2.3`? (edit your question accordingly rather than replying to this comment)

Comment: These should be RGB values, so from 0 to 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])[.]([2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]).([2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])$
```

I test against the following:

```
0.0.0
1.3.2
2.6.4
3.9.6
4.12.8
5.15.10
6.18.12
7.21.14
8.24.16
9.27.18
10.30.20
11.33.22
12.36.24
13.39.26
14.42.28
15.45.30
16.48.32
17.51.34
18.54.36
19.57.38
20.60.40
21.63.42
22.66.44
23.69.46
24.72.48
25.75.50
26.78.52
27.81.54
28.84.56
29.87.58
30.90.60
31.93.62
32.96.64
33.99.66
34.102.68
35.105.70
36.108.72
37.111.74
38.114.76
39.117.78
40.120.80
41.123.82
42.126.84
43.129.86
44.132.88
45.135.90
46.138.92
47.141.94
48.144.96
49.147.98
50.150.100
51.153.102
52.156.104
53.159.106
54.162.108
55.165.110
56.168.112
57.171.114
58.174.116
59.177.118
60.180.120
61.183.122
62.186.124
63.189.126
64.192.128
65.195.130
66.198.132
67.201.134
68.204.136
69.207.138
70.210.140
71.213.142
72.216.144
73.219.146
74.222.148
75.225.150
76.228.152
77.231.154
78.234.156
79.237.158
80.240.160
81.243.162
82.246.164
83.249.166
84.252.168
255.255.255
1.2.3
87.261.174
88.264.176
89.267.178
90.270.180
91.273.182
92.276.184
93.279.186
94.282.188
95.285.190
96.288.192
97.291.194
98.294.196
99.297.198
100.300.200
101.303.202
102.306.204
103.309.206
104.312.208
105.315.210
106.318.212
107.321.214
108.324.216
109.327.218
110.330.220
111.333.222
112.336.224
113.339.226
114.342.228
115.345.230
116.348.232
117.351.234
118.354.236
119.357.238
120.360.240
121.363.242
122.366.244
123.369.246
124.372.248
125.375.250
126.378.252
127.381.254
128.384.256
129.387.258
130.390.260
131.393.262
132.396.264
133.399.266
134.402.268
135.405.270
136.408.272
137.411.274
138.414.276
139.417.278
140.420.280
141.423.282
142.426.284
143.429.286
144.432.288
145.435.290
146.438.292
147.441.294
148.444.296
149.447.298
150.450.300
151.453.302
152.456.304
153.459.306
154.462.308
155.465.310
156.468.312
157.471.314
158.474.316
159.477.318
160.480.320
161.483.322
162.486.324
163.489.326
164.492.328
165.495.330
166.498.332
167.501.334
168.504.336
169.507.338
170.510.340
171.513.342
172.516.344
173.519.346
174.522.348
175.525.350
176.528.352
177.531.354
178.534.356
179.537.358
180.540.360
181.543.362
182.546.364
183.549.366
184.552.368
185.555.370
186.558.372
187.561.374
188.564.376
189.567.378
190.570.380
191.573.382
192.576.384
193.579.386
194.582.388
195.585.390
196.588.392
197.591.394
198.594.396
199.597.398
200.600.400
201.603.402
202.606.404
203.609.406
204.612.408
205.615.410
206.618.412
207.621.414
208.624.416
209.627.418
210.630.420
211.633.422
212.636.424
213.639.426
214.642.428
215.645.430
216.648.432
217.651.434
218.654.436
219.657.438
220.660.440
221.663.442
222.666.444
223.669.446
224.672.448
225.675.450
226.678.452
227.681.454
228.684.456
229.687.458
230.690.460
231.693.462
232.696.464
233.699.466
234.702.468
235.705.470
236.708.472
237.711.474
238.714.476
239.717.478
240.720.480
241.723.482
242.726.484
243.729.486
244.732.488
245.735.490
246.738.492
247.741.494
248.744.496
249.747.498
250.750.500
251.753.502
252.756.504
253.759.506
254.762.508
255.765.510
256.768.512
257.771.514
258.774.516
259.777.518
260.780.520
261.783.522
262.786.524
263.789.526
264.792.528
265.795.530
266.798.532
267.801.534
268.804.536
269.807.538
270.810.540
271.813.542
225.816.5441
273.819.546
274.8221.548
2725.8252.550
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(0+)(\.\1){2}$
```

meaning:

```
^        # the start of the input
(0+)     # match one ore more `0`'s and store it in group 1
(        # start group 2
  \.\1   #   match a literal `.` and match whatever group 1 matched
){2}     # end group 2 and repeat it twice
$        # the end of the input
```

And if you just need 3 block of at most 3 digits, do this:

```
^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){2}$
```

or

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$
```

Note that this will also match `"777.888.999"`, but validating numerical ranges with regex isn't what regex is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your pattern

```
 /^[0-9]{1,3}$/.{1}/^[0-9]{1,3}$/.{1}^[0-9]{1,3}$/
```

1. `^` is the anchor for the start of the string, `$` for the end.
2. To escape a special character use the backslash
3. `{1}` is superfluous.

So we end up here:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30rbn)

But this checks only the pattern! It will accept also e.g. 000, 256 and 999, but matching a certain number range is difficult and needs a much more complex regex.

The pattern that checks also for the range, would look like this (I did only a quick test!)

```
^(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:.(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}$
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30rc3)

**I would not recommend doing it that way!**

Answer (score -2):

If you want to match RGB values then use ranges:

```
^[0-256]{1,3}(\.[0-256]{1,3}){2}$
```

Comment: This will not work because the first part says give me a range 0-2 and match the character 5 and 6; 1 to 3 times. 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 will be the only numbers matched 33 wouldn't match or 199.